# Why is the mock data unit test failing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-unittest

I am writing a unit test with mock data for one of my functions.

Previously the response of my function looked like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "a": 2264,
            "b": "Comp PT"
        }
    ],
    "success": True
}
```

The unit test was written for this, and the test was passing as well. But due to some requirements the response is a little different from the previous one as shown below:

```
{
    "data": {
        "data": [
            {
                "a": 2264,
                "b": "Comp PT"
            }
        ],
        "status": "In Progress",
        "c": "5"
    },
    "success": true
}
```

Now my test is failing with this error:

```
FAILED (failures=1)

200 != 500
Expected :500
Actual   :200
```

The mock data is passed as `self.get_nano` inside the test file as shown below:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
from src.rest_apis.web_app import app
from src.v1.tests.test_main import MockTestBase


class TestSimulationConfig(MockTestBase):

@patch('<path_to>.SimulationResult')
@patch('<path_to>.execute_query')
def test_get_abc(self, mock_query_execut, mock_sim_result):
    mock_query_execut.return_value = {'result': self.get_nano['data']}
    mock_sim_result.get_selected_components.return_value = self.get_nano

    api_url = f'<path_to_api>'
    response = self.app.get(api_url, content_type='application/json', follow_redirects=True)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: Is it because `"success": true` should be `"success": True` to be properly defined?

Comment: What is that response supposed to be? Is that a JSON string or is that a Python dictionary? If it is the former `true` is valid and `True` is not. If it is the latter, it is the other way around.